# Setting UDP Port for receiving multicast packets and handling port conflicts

Tags: sockets, networking, ip, port, multicast

Lets say there is a LAN where several hosts have an instance of some application running.

Each instance of that application intends to receive packets sent to a particular Multicast IP Address on some port (say 5000).

For this to happen, at each host the application needs to bind socket on the port 5000.

If that port is not available on one of the hosts (i.e. a different application socket has occupied it), what are the ways to handle such a scenario?

---

In short,

1) What to do when an application intending to receive multicast packets on a particular port runs into a Port Conflict?

2) What are the best practices, if any, to choose a UDP port for this purpose?

Comment: About all you can do is make sure everybody sets `SO_REUSEPORT` before they bind. If the port is already taken, you're out of luck, unless you can devise a distributed port allocation system.

Comment: @EJP Thanks for the reply. Are there any real world scenarios where such a "distributed port allocation system" is employed? Can you point to some resources which I can study to get some ideas?